# Selecting duplicate records

Tags: excel, duplicates

I need to copy all the duplicates in a certain sheet, but can't remove. I'm in Excel.

Data samples:

Line_***_****ID****_*__*_*__*_*__*_***_Value

1_***_*___***1****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**_14

2_***_*___***1****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**_134

3_***_*___***2****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**_15

4_***_*___***2****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**_15

5_***_*___***3****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**_17

6_***_*___***3****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**_16

7_***_*___***3****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**_17

I need to do a CRTL+C in those lines with both duplicated, like lines 3 and 4; and lines 5 and 7.

Comment: Simply doing a CRTL+C, moving it to the clipboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Copy` method.

```
Range("D4:E5").Copy
```

There. You've copied that range to the clipboard. Assuming that's what mean by "doing a CRTL+C"...

I wonder what exactly you're planning to do once this is in the clipboard.

Comment: I plan to paste it to another sheet. The main problem is that I can't copy just the duplicates. I wondered if there's a way.

Comment: Just write a loop, for each entry checking whether it's in your list more than once.

Comment: Yeah, I did that! Thank you. I appreciated the help.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the Advanced Filter from the Data->Filter menu, and check the box for Unique Values.  Then cut and paste what you want.  Then turn it back off.